# How to make status bar translucent?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar

i need help in making status bar translucent. In some parts of app its working fine, and in other its not.

[image: Status bar black]

This is how status bar  is coming if i show navugation bar.

[image: status bar translucent]

this is how is showing when i remove the navigation bar.
I need to show the navigation bar but status bar should be translucent. The background image is pushed down with the navigation bar.I have set the background image programmatically making a base class.

```
-(void)addBackGroundImage{

self.backGroundImage=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
self.backGroundImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
[self.backGroundImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
self.backGroundImage.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
[self.view addSubview:self.backGroundImage];

[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.backGroundImage];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_backGroundImage]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_backGroundImage)]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(0)-[_backGroundImage]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_backGroundImage)]];

AppDelegate *objAppDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, 20)];
view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[view setAlpha:0.2];
}

-(void)updateBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)bgImage{

[self.backGroundImage setImage:bgImage];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually what you need to completely remove default header background (statusBar + navigationBar) and set your own:

```
// ViewController.m

self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor yourColor]; // Set your tint color
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.opaque = NO;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 64)];
bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your_Background_Image"]];
[self.view addSubview:bgView];
```

Comment: There is an image on the navigation bar that i want to show. That image covers navigation bar and not status bar, sorry if my question is not clear.

Comment: Me again updated the answer for set your appropriately tint color of navigation elements.

Comment: Have made the changes, and have marked your answer. thankyou :)